# iOS apps log users out when upgrading to a new phone

Tags: ios, authentication

Why do so many apps log users out after upgrading to a new phone ? (ex: Gmail, Slack, Instagram).

From a technical POV it's easy to keep the user logged in after a phone upgrade.

Is there any upside to logging the user out?

Comment: from a technical POV isn't easier, it's almost impossible

Comment: Credentials saved in the keychain persist when migrating from one phone to the next if you transfer data over or do an iCloud backup restore. You can opt out of that behavior by setting the Device Only keychain accessibility attributes. Firebase definitely does this with stored API refresh / access tokens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do I know it was the real user that upgraded the phone and not some one who shouldn't? That is the security and safety risk that exists in auto migration for accounts between devices. Hence, when a new device attempts to log into a service, the user must resupply their log in to use the service again. Read "Design For Safety", it will discuss these types of concerns that designers must grapple with.